# How to install R3.6 on Ubuntu

Tags: 18.04, r

I found some instructions for installing up to date versions of R but they're all incredibly complicated. I tried them nonetheless, but they didn't work. Is there really no clicky way to get this done?

I tried

```
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran36/'
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E084DAB9
sudo apt update
```

with two different URLs and always get stuff like

```
Get:21 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/ Packages [51.4 kB]
Reading package lists... Done   
E: The repository 'http://www.stats.bris.ac.uk/R/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic/ Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://archive.canonical.com precise Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 40976EAF437D05B5
E: The repository 'http://archive.canonical.com precise Release' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

(I also tried it with --allow-unauthenticated even though it feels uncomfortable having to do this, but that didn't change anything.)

I also tried 
`sudo echo "deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/" >> /etc/apt/sources.list`

but that also didn't help. (this required me to chown that file. This is ridiculous)

By the way, the r-project website itself says stuff like
``To obtain the latest R 3.4 packages, add an entry like

```
deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/
```

``

Finally, not surprisingly, trying to install from source also crashes with the message

```
Configure: error: Maybe check LDFLAGS for paths to Fortran libraries?
```

I need R3.6 because some software I need to run requires it. It almost seems like R3.6 doesn't exist from googling though.

Comment: I've checked at https://cloud.r-project.org/, and the command to add the key is `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9`. Note, how the key is way longer then yours. I recommend trying again.... There is no need to chmod anything, or even run that command, as the repository has been added successfully.

Comment: Oh damn, I might have accidentally copy and pasted that incompletely. Will try again later. But what the heck is all of this anyway? Is there no simpler way?

Comment: Your apt update issues seem to relate to other repositories (perhaps from previous failed installation attempts) - in particular `http://www.stats.bris.ac.uk/R/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic/` and `http://archive.canonical.com precise`

Comment: R packages (`r-base` and `r-recommended`) are already available in the Ubuntu repositories for all supported releases of Ubuntu. However, since Ubuntu packages receive only bugfixes after release, older releases have older versions of R. Example: 18.04 LTS is over a year old, and has a correspondingly older R 3.4. Your problem is caused by your need for the *newest* version of R (3.6) which was released *after* Ubuntu 19.04. 3.6 has since been packaged, and will be in the next release of Ubuntu in October 2019.

Comment: You can try pulling those 19.10 packages from launchpad.net, and installing them onto your 18.04 system. Note that it might break your system and is not supported. If you run into problems, our only advice will be to uninstall the wrong-release packages. Alternately, you can become a tester and install 19.10. However, pre-release has risks - you are discovering and reporting all the problems.

Comment: First of all, what Ubuntu version are you using? Or better... Just answer this: what is the output of the command `apt-cache policy r-base`?

Answer (score 0):

Your error is in the repository you are adding.

https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran36/

Use the bionic-cran35 repository. R3.6 will install fine on ubuntu 18. You can find the instructions on digitalocean

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-r-on-ubuntu-18-04-quickstart

On a previous machine in the spring of 19 I used the 36 repository too, before 35 had r3.6. I ended up installing the 19.10 packages, and that worked ok. I just removed them, and correctly install r3.6 on my machine using the appropriate repository today.